# Failure EOF on Charles

Tags: charles-proxy

I'm getting a "Failure:EOF" when trying to change a request response using "map local" on Charles Proxy. The request keeps loading indefinitely on the web site. Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked the local file you are trying to map to still exists on the file system and Charles has read permissions on it?

Comment: even im getting the same error Failure:EOF, while trying map local feature